# Change size one image into another

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one image into another,layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/rlimageforimage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/emilypic"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/outsideCimage"
        android:src="@drawable/cicon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/dialog_icon"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/dialog_icon"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/dialog_icon"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/dialog_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

where image with id:ousideimage is outside image,but when I change the inner image (doesnt have id) all 2 images changed,but if I change outside image nothing happened.I need to have outside image bigger then inside.How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this below code... 
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rlimageforimage" 
            android:src="@drawable/cicon"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_icon"  
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/emilypic"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Hope this helps...

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/second"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/second"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For outside image you can use layout instead of ImageView, Take a layout and keep background to that layout and take ImageView within that and take some margin, Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/rlimageforimage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cicon"
    android:id="@+id/outsideCimage" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_icon"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/emilypic" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```